# Using variable values inside UPDATE sql command - SQLite (Python)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am getting an

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Error on running the below command in SQLite in Python. Any suggestions?

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE Menu SET ? = ? WHERE restid = ? AND DishID = ?',(self.var1,self.var2,self.var3,self.var4))
```

Where var1 is a column name of the table Menu

Comment: You cannot replace identifiers using SQL parameters.  Also, setting them requires munging the query string.

Comment: Is there a possible way around through which I can refer to my column name using a variable?

Comment: . . Yes, you can use python to replace the variable in the string.